# Find a larger degree permutation representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Recently I have been studying the quaternions, generalized quaternions, and dicyclic groups. Initially, I was interested in finding the minimum degree permutation representations of such groups and was happy to find many resources that helped me.

However, now I am interested in finding 'larger' degree representations. I know that for any finite group $G$ that:
$$
G\hookrightarrow{}S_{|G|}
$$
However, I wish to explore faithful permutation representations of these groups that can be embedded into a symmetric group larger than $S_{|G|}$. Is this a fruitful avenue to explore, and if so, what are the key terms that I should be searching for?

Comment: Strange, as far as I know usually people are rather interested in the the other direction, namely in the *minimal* (or at least a "sharper" than Cayley's) faithful permutation representation. After all, for every $n>m$, you can always embed $S_m$ into $S_n$. But I may be misunderstanding your point/aim.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo No you're completely right in understanding my intention. My ultimate goal is using these 'larger' permutation representations to construct graphs with automorphism groups isomorphic to the above mentioned groups.

Comment: Every faithful action $G\curvearrowright\Omega$ has $\Omega=M\sqcup X$ where $M$ is minimal faithful and $X$ is arbitrary (non-uniquely). Which ones are you interested in? Tangentially, but pre-emptively, do you know that (a) all $G$-sets are disjoint unions of orbits, (b) orbits are equivalent to coset spaces (orbit-stabilizer theorem), (c) the kernel of an action is the intersection of the kernels of the orbits' restricted actions, (d) the kernel of an action on an orbit is the normal core of the stabilizer?

Comment: I suggest to include your comment in the main body, because it provides some possibly meaningful "constraint" to an otherwise limitless research (see comments/answer). Not everybody go through the comments. Accordingly, a tag revision might help.

Comment: @runway44 - I will try to answer each point of your comment to the best of my knowledge. 

(a) Yes, every $G$-set will be a disjoint union of orbits; the sum of these will be the degree of the permutation representation. How to choose these disjoint unions is still a tad hazy for me, but I have a tiny bit of intuition based on some sets that worked for me. I am not interested in any $G$-set where the group action is transitive.
(b) Correct, 'fixing' one integer in a distinct orbit will return a permutation group that is isomorphic to a subgroup of the original group...

Comment: following the orbit stabilizer theorem exactly.
(c) I may be interpreting this a bit differently, as I think the kernel of the action is the union of all kernels for the action on each distinct orbit. Since all the orbits are disjoint, then any intersection of their respective kernels would be empty. 
(d) Since I am not interested in transitive actions, then I don't think this applies.

Comment: (b) I wouldn't, in general, assume the set a group acts on is comprised of numbers. Also, the stabilizer subgroup is not merely "isomorphic" to a subgroup of $G$, it *is* a subgroup of $G$. (c) The kernel of an action on a set is the collection of all group elements that fix all elements of the set. Orbits may be disjoint in $\Omega$, but their kernels in $G$ are not. Indeed, all kernels are normal subgroups, so they can't be. (d) It still applies because it tells you which orbits you can use to construct your desired $G$-set:

Comment: write $\Omega=G/H_1\sqcup\cdots\sqcup G/H_k$ where the intersection of the normal cores of the $H_i$s is trivial (add multiple copies of the orbits as desired). You didn't answer my most important question, though: now that I've said a recipe for how to construct every possible faithful action (namely $\Omega=M\sqcup X$ where $M$ is minimal faithful and $X$ is arbitrary, nonuniquely), which ones are you interested in? You mentioned in a comment below you want it to be fixed-point free. Okay, what else?

Comment: Thanks @runway44 for the clarifications, I truly appreciate the help.  (b) As I'm interested in how a graph automorphism group acts on the vertex set, it is usually easiest to enumerate all vertices and use this set as the $G$-set. (c) Of course, my mistake. I am seeking actions where the kernel is trivial. (d) I'm still trying to wrap my head around this, as I've never really thought of this relation before. I'm working out some examples to really sink this in and I will be able to speak to this shortly.

Comment: As you said, I'm looking for $G$-sets corresponding to faithful actions on a fixed-point free set; this in turn corresponds to the vertex set of a connected graph. I'm still mulling over what additional assumptions need to be made.

Answer (score 1):

We have  $S_m\hookrightarrow S_n$, for $n\ge m$, in a natural way (leave $\{m+1,\dots,n\}$ fixed, say).

As far as the embedding,  you could just  compose the above with the Cayley embedding,  $G\hookrightarrow S_{|G|}$,  to get one into $S_n$ for any $n\ge |G|$.

So the answer to your question is yes, and this amounts to a fairly trivial add-on to the Cayley theorem.

Comment: While I see the point of your argument, I am looking for permutation representations of a given group where no integer or 'point' remains fixed. Otherwise, the graphs I would be looking to construct would have unnecessary edges and vertices that are fixed under any graph automorphism. This would leave me in the same boat as if I were to use my minimal permutation representation.

Comment: Once we have $G\hookrightarrow S_n$, it seems pretty clear that for an embedding $G\hookrightarrow S_m$, where $m\gt n$, we will have  fixed points.

Comment: As a counterexample, $Dic_3$ is the dicyclic group of order 12, which naturally has a permutation representation in $S_{12}$. However, I am able to construct an isomorphic permutation representation of degree 17, where no point is left fixed.

Comment: @Jdella, what is an "isomorphic permutation representation"? In particular, "isomorphic" to what?

Comment: A permutation group of degree 17 that is isomorphic to $Dic_3$ .

Comment: I think you're talking about a faithful action;  whereas I'm talking about at least one of the stabilizers being the whole group.

Comment: @Cpc My apologies, I should've specified that I'm only interested in faithful actions.

Comment: No apology necessary.   But with my answer the action on a set of $n$ letters will be faithful.   Each element of $G$ when considered as a degree $n$ permutation will move something.   Just,  and this was my point, there will be $n-m$ letters which are never moved.